# Android fragmentation and target versions

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if there are any references to the cons of targeting Android 2.3.3 vs 4.0. On the programming side or user side.

Also On google there is a pie chart showing the fragmentation of Android Versions, is there a similar chart or information that shows the fragmentation by country, if a Application was only relative to the USA for example.

Thanks.

Comment: At least you can get away with 2.3.3.  I've been trying to convince a client to go with a newer version, but so far I'm stuck with targeting 2.1.  The client liaison person has an old phone with 2.1 and demands that the app works on his phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you must determine reasons why you want to require 4.0 for implementation from developer side, but client is the one which has to make decision about targeted devices / market and functionalities. You have to inform client what is it what you can implement or what is it what is restricted.

To help to determine what is it from user side you must take a look from users point of view and present all possibilities from that.

I think that you can start with comparative view where are displayed both versions and regarding this make your answer. [Look at this link](http://www.androidauthority.com/android-2-3-gingerbread-vs-android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich-37742/).

Note that you should not limit the client  based on your preferences, because a customer will leave if he finds the fact that what he was looking for feasible on a platform that is required, and you did not do just because of your preference.

Comment: Nice link. Good find. I believe I may have found a solution, because of the hardware and graphic intensity of their app (it is a business app that they wanted to have animations, and bitmaps, and sparkly "game like" presentation) that We will initially build for 4.0, and then downgrade and build for 2.3.3, because a few features they requested were not added until 4.0, and I will have to remove/substitute for them in 2.3.3, so the market will use the app built for the correct version, that way 4.0+ users can a full experience. Also because 2.3 is being shoved out, albeit not as fast as id like

Answer (score 2):

The cons would be you do not have access to a lot of 4.0 and higher features. There are a bunch, too many to list, but I recommend starting development as low as possible and increasing as you realize you need more and more features.

All devices have backwards compatibility with earlier versions of Android. Therefore, you can reach more users with a lower API but risk not being able to implement certain features. The pros to go with 4.0

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html#UserFeatures

and for the developer

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html#DeveloperApis

Answer (score 1):

I have found targeting API 10 with the support library and ActionBarSherlock to be very reasonable after getting past the initial learning curve.